# Using String as _id in CursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

It's a requirement of using a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) that:

> The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

It's clear from the `getItemId()` signature, and the CursorAdapter source, that this column is expected to be an integral type:

```
/**
 * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
 */
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
        if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return mCursor.getLong(mRowIDColumn);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'd really like to be able to use another column which contains text (UUID strings) as my `_id`, but it doesn't look like that's directly possible.

If my database schema (which is defined externally) does not include an integer `_id` column, what options do I have for coercing a non-integer column, or manufacturing an `_id` column in the query output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If my database schema (which is defined externally) does not include an integer _id column, what options do I have for coercing a non-integer column, or manufacturing an _id column in the query output?

Each sqlite row has a unique `ROWID` that is an integer. You can select it as the ID:

```
String[] columns = new String[] { "rowid AS _id", ... };
```

If your table happens to have an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column, it will be aliased with the rowid.

Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid